# Excel VBA: How to create a Macro to copy fields, location is decided based on same value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with the following problem:
I want to copy a range of fields (E18:BE18) from sheet1 to Sheet 2.
The issue is, however, that the row it should be copied in is dependent on the value in sheet1.C15. This value should be found in the B-column in Sheet2.

For instance if Sheet2.B10 has the same value as Sheet1.C15, then the range Sheet1.(E18:BE18) should be copied to Sheet2.(E10:BE10).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
Dim objSheetA As Worksheet
Dim objSheetB As Worksheet

Set objSheetA = Worksheets("SheetA")
Set objSheetB = Worksheets("SheetB")

If objSheetB.Cells(10, 2).Value = objSheetA.Cells(15, 3).Value Then
     objSheetA.Range(Cells(18, 5), Cells(18, 57)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     objSheetB.Select
     objSheetB.Cells(10, 5).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, although the only point I would like to make is that I don't know which field in sheet 2 is going to be equal to C15. There are about 100 rows and one of those rows contains the same value. Using the B10 was merely an example. I know it's in column B, but don't know the row number. Similar for when copying the range. I know it's E until BE, but don't know which row it will be in.

Comment: @PhilippeMarquet in this case, you can using loop to check value in column B and get row of range. I don't know condition to get row in range E until BE so if you provide that condition, I think can help you solve this problem